# Is there a connection between the concepts of limits in ordinals, functions and categories?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

In set theory there is the concept of a limit ordinal: Nonzero ordinals that are the supermum of all ordinals below them.

In functional analysis there are the concepts of limits of functions (and sequences) a value that the function comes arbitrarily close to at a point.

And in category theory there is a concept of a limit which is a universal cone.

Is there something common about all these ideas that justifies them all being called limits or is it a coincidence of language ?

Comment: It is really a coincidence of language. Just because the word "limit" appears throughout, there is no reason to expect any connection. Mathematics is overloaded with words like "limit, regular, normal, simple, proper, ...", and sometimes words overlap.

Comment: For example, there is a notion of normal subgroup of a group, of normal bundle of a regular manifold, of normal closure of a field extension, and they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I would say that in this specific case there is a lot of connection. Also, it seems to me that *proper* is always used in one meaning (btw, I've rarely seen *simple* to mean something other then an algebraic structure without proper non-trivial congruences, but not sure here). Though, you are right that in general words have tons of meanings in mathematics.

Comment: @lisyarus I agree they are connected in this case, but people defined all three concepts without specifically thinking about this connection, I would dare to say. The fact that both categorical limits and topological limits are malleable enough allows for the connection to be made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are all special cases of limits in the category-theoretic sense.

Limit ordinals are a special case of least upper bounds in partially ordered sets.  Given a partially ordered set $(X,\le)$, we may form a category whose objects are elements of $X$ where there is a single morphism from $x$ to $y$ whenever $x\le y$.  Transitivity gives us composition and reflexivity gives us identity morphisms.  In that case, the least upper bound of some subset $Y\subset X$ is precisely the limit of the diagram spanned by $Y$.

The limits of functions and sequences that we study in functional analysis and, more generally, in topology are in fact also a special case of least upper bounds in partially ordered sets, so they are also generalized by category-theoretic limits.  If $X$ is a (topological) space, a *filter* on $X$ is a set $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $X$ such that:

- $\emptyset\not\in\mathcal F$
- If $Y\in\mathcal F$ and $Y\subset Z$ then $Z\in\mathcal F$
- If $Y,Z\in\mathcal F$ then $Y\cap Z\in\mathcal F$

As an example, if $x\in X$ then the set of all neighbourhoods of $x$ (i.e., subsets of $X$ that contain some open neighbourhood of $x$) is a filter on $X$, called the *neighbourhood filter* $\mathcal N_x$.  We say a filter $\mathcal F$ *converges to $x$*, and write $\mathcal F\to x$, if $\mathcal N_x\subset\mathcal F$.

What has this to do with convergence of sequences and functions?  Well, suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$.  Then we can define a filter $\mathcal S_{(x_n)}$ by:

$$
S_{(x_n)} = \left\{Y\subset X\;\colon\;\exists N \;.\;\textrm{if }n\ge N\textrm{ then }x_n\in Y\right\}
$$

the set of all subsets of $X$ that eventually contain every term of the sequence.  You can check for yourself that $x_n\to x$ if and only if $\mathcal N_x\subset S_{(x_n)}$.

Limits of functions can be handled in a similar way.  Now, given some space $X$, we may define a partially ordered set $F$ whose elements are the filters on $X$, ordered by inclusion.  Let $\mathcal F$ be a filter whose limit we want to find.  For example, we might have $\mathcal F=S_{(x_n)}$ for some sequence $(x_n)$.  Given $x\in X$, define
$$
\mathcal L_{\mathcal F,x}=\left\{\mathcal G\in F\;\colon\; \mathcal G\subset\mathcal F, \mathcal G\to x\right\}
$$
Then $\mathcal F\to x$ if and only if $\mathcal F$ is the least upper bound in $F$ for $\mathcal L_{\mathcal F, x}$.

Comment: If you talk about filters and convergence, then you might as well mention model theoretic definitions of a limit modulo an ultrafilter, and the measure theoretic generalization of a limit in measure, which is essentially a limit of a filter. There is no "base notion", and each of these things can be expressed in terms of the other.

Answer (score 4):

To connect ordinals and analysis, one puts the [*order topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) on ordinals. Then, given a metric space (or topological space) $X$, a sequence is just a function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$, or, using the first countable ordinal $f: \omega\rightarrow X$. It now happens that a sequence converges iff it can be extended to a function $f':\omega +1 \rightarrow X$, such that $f'(n)=f(n)$ for all $n \in \omega$ and $f'$ is continuous with respect to the order topology on $\omega + 1$.

Then, to connect ordinals and category theory, take the category of all ordinals and, say, increasing maps between them. We use the fact that for any two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, one of them embeds into the other as an initial segment. For any set $A$ of ordinals form a diagram with this embedding maps. Then, the [*categorical limit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) of this diagram is precisely the limit in the sence of ordinals: it will be the supremum (limit) of all ordinals from $A$, and the limit maps will embed ordinals from $A$ into this limit.

Answer (score 1):

I like this question and I look forwards to seeing other answers.
Until then, here's a thin connection.

In elementary calculus, one is taught that the limit of a monotonic function can
be obtained by considering its supremum. Then when one peaks into the world of
order theory (eg probability theory) then the notion of a continous function is
defined to be one that preserves certain suprema and suprema are even sometimes
called limits in such contexts. Now, the notion of a product, in set theory,
can also be construed as a limit, as a supremum: given sets $A, B$, define

```
P₀ ≔ ∅
Pₙ₊₁ ≔ P ∪ {(a,b)} where a ∈ A are b ∈ B selected such that (a,b) ∉ Pₙ
```

Then we have $A×B = limₙ Pₙ = ⋃ₙ Pₙ = ⋃_{a ∈ A, b ∈ B} \{(a,b)\}$.

Hope this helps a bit.